# What is the fastest way of doing this computation in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, computation

I'm using the profiler on my MATLAB code, and the following line is taking 50% of the code's computation time:

```
firstSide = -1*HessianInverse*(eye(n,n)- ...
currentA'(currentA*HessianInverse*currentA')^-1*currentA*HessianInverse)*currentG;
```

- HessianInverse is an n x n matrix
- currentG is an n x n matrix
- currentA is an n x n matrix as well

What would be the fastest way of doing this computation?

Comment: Use `inv` rather than `^-1`. Also should `currentA'(currentA*Hes...` have a `*` or something?

Comment: Shouldn't `currentA'*(currentA*HessianInverse*currentA)^-1*currentA*HessianInverse=eye(n,n)`? In which case this equation should be zero?

Comment: If it's resolved, post your answer and accept it, don't wipe out the contents of your question.

Answer (score 2):

You can do two simple things:

- Compute `currentA*HessianInverse` once and store the result, since your are using the same matrix multiplication in two different places.
- Replace `^-1` with the `\` operator, since the latter is about twice as fast:

For example

```
>> A = rand(1000);
>> B = rand(1000);

>> tic; A^-1*B; toc
Elapsed time is 0.592531 seconds.
>> tic; A^-1*B; toc
Elapsed time is 0.578318 seconds.

>> tic; A\B; toc
Elapsed time is 0.275542 seconds.
>> tic; A\B; toc
Elapsed time is 0.262008 seconds.
```